# Could somebody tell me where the heck the IndexError is? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble figuring out where the IndexError in the code is so could somebody help me out

Here's the code

```
def gap(g, m, n):
    def is_prime(n):
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    result = []
    r = []
    primes = [p for p in range(m, n) if is_prime(p)]
    for i in range(len(primes) - 1):
        if primes[i] - primes[i + 1] == g:
            r.append(primes[i - 1])
            r.append(primes[i])
    result.append(r[0])
    result.append(r[1])
    if result == []:
        return None
    else:
        return result
print (gap(2, 100, 110))
```

and here's the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\editable.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (gap(2, 100, 110))
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\editable.py", line 14, in gap
    result.append(r[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Well, it says so right there in the trace, right? Line 14 is throwing that error. You called `gap` with parameters `2, 100, 110` and it threw the index error at line 14, when you did `result.append(r[0])`

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason for an error.

```
r.append(primes[i - 1])
```

It takes i as first value id of list and you pass (i - 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(primes) - 1):
    if primes[i] - primes[i + 1] == g:
        r.append(primes[i - 1])
        r.append(primes[i])
result.append(r[0])
result.append(r[1])
```

You have defined r to be an empty array and is still and empty array after the loop. You can check it by adding a simple print statement. So its an array without an index 0 or 1 so it throws out that error.